# Why is my rectangle not horizontally centered?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to use TikZ to draw a rectangle inside an A4 piece of paper,
with an exact 8mm margin around the rectangle.
I found that in landscape mode,
an A4 piece of paper has the dimensions 297 x 210 mm.
So, I calculated that with an 8mm margin,
my rectangle should be 281 x 194 mm.

When I wrote this into code,
my output seems to have a larger margin on the left than on the right.
Why is this the case?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage[margin=8mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

% suppress page numbers
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (28.1,19.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: after {document} add `\noindent`

Comment: @percusse Why does that work and why is it necessary?

Comment: Because the default settings are that the first paragraph is indented (except after section headings). To TeX a `tikzpicture` is linke any other character: just a box that has to be positioned. See the behavior if you had test inctead of a picture.  The begining of the paragraph will be indented.

Comment: @percusse Could you please submit your comment as answer, with a short explanation as to why it works and why it is necessary, and I will accept it?

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to percusse's solution you can use `current page` node to fix the desired rectangle. It uses `remember picture` then you need to compile twice before obtaining the correct result.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage[margin=8mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

% suppress page numbers
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw ([shift={(8mm,8mm)}]current page.south west) rectangle ([shift={(-8mm,-8mm)}]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]